# Command Cooldown ignore users

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I added a command cooldown but how to make it work for only selected users.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel i searched in google i not found any codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to do this, but you can define your own subclass of `Command` that deals with this, since in the async branch, the cooldown is checked in the `prepare()` method:

```
admin_ids = ['1234567', '234567876543', '123454321']

class CommandWithCooldown(commands.Command):
    async def prepare(self, ctx):
        try:
            return await super().prepare(ctx)
        except commands.CommandOnCooldown as e:
            if ctx.message.author.id in admin_ids:
                return
            else:
                raise e


@bot.command(pass_context=True , cls=CommandWithCooldown)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

IMO, this is a more simplistic way to accomplish your task than to handle the error.

Comment: Change it to `ctx.message.server.id`

Comment: When bot restarts cooldown resets so how to make it count from previous usage. If limit is 5 per day and if member used 3 and if bot restarts it should start from were it left for all members.

Comment: @Demotry you need to write to a file or a db which stores the cooldown info. But that is above the context of this current QA, you'll need to ask another question to get a more thorough help, since there's a lot to implement and not enough room in a short comment.

Comment: A possible start is to look into how you would store the cool down bucket (`Command._bucket`) when the program ends and use it when the bot restarts. This feature isn't officially supported so you would have to browse through the source codes and find a way to implement this.